# Entity Framework not making association and displays junction tables

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design

We're trying to setup a new database and application using database first entity framework.

Everything is working well except for this bunch of tables.
The entity framework isn't setup an association and is instead showing the junction tables in 2 of the 3 instances.

In the picture, ProfileIntegrationToolkit and ProfileProviderPrimary should disapear and should instead be associations.

[image: Entity framework diagram]

Here's the code to reproduce the tables

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AuthorizedType]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuthorizedType](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NameEng] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [NameFra] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionEng] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DescriptionFra] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuthorizedToOperateTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IntegrationToolkit]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IntegrationToolkit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NameEng] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [NameFra] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionEng] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DescriptionFra] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IntegrationToolkits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Profile]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AuthorizedToOperateTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuthorizationDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderPrimaryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProviderSecondaryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IntegrationToolkitId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CyberSecurityProfile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit](
    [ProfileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IntegrationToolkitId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CyberSecurityProfileIntegrationToolKitOther] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileId] ASC,
    [IntegrationToolkitId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary](
    [ProfileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProviderId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CyberSecurityProfileCredentialProviderPrimary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileId] ASC,
    [ProviderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary](
    [ProfileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProviderId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CyberSecurityProfileCredentialProviderSecondary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileId] ASC,
    [ProviderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Provider]    Script Date: 25/02/2016 3:04:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Provider](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NameEng] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [NameFra] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionEng] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DescriptionFra] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CredentialProviders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AuthorizedToOperate] FOREIGN KEY([AuthorizedToOperateTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AuthorizedType] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AuthorizedToOperate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProvidersPrimary] FOREIGN KEY([ProviderPrimaryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Provider] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProvidersPrimary]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProvidersSecondary] FOREIGN KEY([ProviderSecondaryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Provider] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProvidersSecondary]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Profile_IntegrationToolkit] FOREIGN KEY([IntegrationToolkitId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IntegrationToolkit] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Profile_IntegrationToolkit]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileIntegrationToolKit_Profile] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Profile] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileIntegrationToolKit_Profile]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileIntegrationToolKit_IntegrationToolkit] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IntegrationToolkit] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileIntegrationToolKit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileIntegrationToolKit_IntegrationToolkit]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderPrimary_Provider] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Provider] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderPrimary_Provider]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderPrimary_Profile] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Profile] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderPrimary_Profile]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderSecondary_Provider] FOREIGN KEY([ProviderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Provider] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderSecondary_Provider]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderSecondary_Profile] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Profile] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderSecondary] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderSecondary_Profile]
GO
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I've tried re-creating the constraints in SSMS but same result.

---

Edit 1-
If i try reducing the amount of tables I import.  I get similar issues.

[image: Small subset from Entity framework]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a sneaky one! See this part of the DDL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProfileProviderPrimary]  WITH CHECK
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProfileProviderPrimary_Provider]

    FOREIGN KEY([ProfileId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[Provider] ([Id])
```

I indented the errant line. The foreign key to `Provider` should be off `ProviderId`, just as in `ProfileProviderSecondary`. The same error occurs in `ProfileIntegrationToolKit`.

Correct this, remove the junctions from the edmx, update the model from the database and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try in the morning.  hmm I'll have to see why that happeneded when I created the foreign key relation in the diagram mode of SSMS (so that this doesn't happen again)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I guess I wasn't paying attention in the diagram mode of SSMS when creating my foreign key relationship.  Thanks again!